# How do I add up all integers in a range?

Tags: c#, range

I am fairly new to C# and I am currently working on some problems to help build my skills.

Question:
Given two integers `a` and `b`, which can be positive or negative, find the sum of all the numbers between including them too and return it. If the two numbers are equal, return `a` or `b`.

My code:

```cs
using System;
public class Sum
{
    public int GetSum(int a, int b)
    {
        var list;  
        list.AddRange(Enumerable.range(a,b));
        for(var i=0; i <= list.length; i++);
        var sum;
        sum = sum + i;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Also, if I'm doing a bad practice let me know.

Comment: Hints: 1) you're never initializing `list`. 2) Your `<=` should be `<` as otherwise you'll go off the end of it. 3) `list.length` should be `list.Count` if you're using a `List<int>`. 4) You don't need to create a list at all - just use a loop to go from `a` to `b` and add up the values.

Comment: What's the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: 5) Your `for` loop is empty and does nothing.

Comment: (Admittedly when you start learning about LINQ, there's a one-line version using `Enumerable.Range` - but not quite the way that you've got it at the moment... check the documentation carefully.)

Comment: I am prety sure Enumerable.Range() was the exactly wrong tool all along. It does not do anything close to your stated goal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not required to use a loop, I'd probably use Gauß:

1. The sum of all integers from `1` to `n` is `n*(n+1)/2`.
2. The sum of all integers between a and b is equal to the sum of all integers from `1` to `b` *minus* the sum of all integers from `1` to `a-1`.

That said, the formula is

```
public static int GetSum(int a, int b) {
    return (b*(b+1) - (a-1)*a) / 2;
}
```

Edit: this formula assumes `a < b`. If necessary, perform a check and throw an exception, or swap variables if you are alright with saying "the sum of all integers from 11 to 10 is 21":

```
public static int GetSum(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) {
        return (b*(b+1) - (a-1)*a) / 2;
    } else if (a == b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(a)} must be less than or equal to {nameof(b)}.").
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work if both integers or only 1 is negative? Mathy Solutions often have conflicting requirements for the numbers.

Comment: @Christopher @ShamPooSham: As long as `a < b`, this also works for a and b `< 1`, because the principle of equal partial sums is true into the negative range as well. You are right about `a == b` or `a > b`, so I extended my answer to cover those cases.

Comment: That being said, I'd appreciate if before claiming "this doesn't work if a or b is negative" you'd do the Maths and check that, because it absolutely works. ;)

Comment: If `a == b`, the sum is `a` (or `b`). And it works with your formula without special treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the traditional **for loop** solution, you can use `(firstNumber + lastNumber)*totalNumbers/2` formula to get the sum of every number between two ranges.

```cs
public static int GetSumBetweenTwoRanges(int firstNumber, int lastNumber){
    return (firstNumber + lastNumber)*totalNumbers/2;
}
```

Comment: It seems like LWChris beat you too that answer, with better explanation too.

Comment: I think that the LWChris answer is too complex for beginners. Note that this is more simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int GetSum(int a, int b)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(a, b-a+1).Sum();
}
```

which is essentially doing the same as

```
public int GetSum2(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (var element in Enumerable.Range(a, b - a + 1))
    {
        sum += element;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: An answer without explanation of what its doing and also not explaining where the op code is wrong gets my downvote.

Comment: Like Christopher's answer, I don't see that this will actually be useful to the questioner.

Comment: @Christopher The reason why this isn't helpful is because it's just code but no explanation

Comment: @Christopher: You don't know that I "keep downvoting". I haven't downvoted anything on this set of posts. And 45 minutes ago, I wrote: "But basically, a code-only answer isn't going to help the questioner learn what's wrong with their code, or improve. You could have offered advice based on their existing code, as well as offering potentially multiple solutions, each clearly-explained - but instead it's just a code dump." In what way is that "strictly avoiding any hint what is wrong so people can improve"? (And that was the only time I used the word "wrong", too.)

Answer (score 0):

**Tips**

With 2 methods:

> 1. `CreatedData` from **2** args
> 2. Do work

```
        private IEnumerable<int> CreateData(int a,int b)
        {
            // Get min and max to loop
            int min= 0, max= 0;
            if (a < b)
            {
                min = a;
                max = b;
            }
            else if (b < a)
            {
                min = b;
                max = a;
            }
            for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
        private int CalcSum(int a, int b) // Your target
        {
            List<int> lst = CreateData(a, b).ToList();
            if (lst.Count == 1) // This means: a = b
                return a;
            return lst.Sum();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile. This being said, let me analyse your code:

1. C# is case sensitive. Therefore you must write `Enumerable.Range`, not `Enumerable.range`.
2. The second parameter of [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) is a `count`, not the upper limit. So you would have to write

   ```
   Enumerable.Range(a, b - a + 1)
   ```
3. You add this range to a list. This is not necessary. You could directly loop over this range with

   ```
   foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(a, b - a + 1)) { ... }
   ```
4. You don't initialize the list. You should write

   ```
   var list = new List<int>();
   ```
5. List has no `length` property. It has a `Count` property. (An array would have a `Length` property.)
6. A list index goes from `0` to `list.Count - 1`! This means that you should write `i < list.Count` (not `<=`) in the for-loop.
7. It is not necessary to use a list or an `Enumerable.Range` at all. Simply write

   ```
   for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) { ... }
   ```

   and sum up `i` directly.
8. In the for loop, you write `var i=0;`. This is not wrong; however, the `var` keyword has been introduced to avoid writing complex type names twice as in `List<string[]> words = new List<string[]>();`. You can write `var words = new List<string[]>();`. You must use `var` when you create anonymous types like in `var a = new { Name = "Test", Count = 5 };`, because this type has no name in C#. For an `int` type I simply would write `int` instead of `var`. In fact it is a good practice to do this for all primitive types like `int`, `string`, `bool` etc.
9. Your loop is empty, because you terminated it with a semicolon (`;`). `for` only considers the next statement as being part of the loop body. That would be `var sum;` if you dropped this `;`. Drop this `;` and instead enclose all the statements of the loop body in curly braces `{ }`. This is called a compound statement. `return sum;` comes after the right curly brace.
10. `var sum;` does not compile, as C# cannot infer the type of the variable  (the same is true for `var list;`). Either write `int sum;` or `var sum = 0` to let C# infer the type from the initialization expression (`= 0`).
11. `sum` is not initialized. In C#, local variables are not automatically initialized.
12. `sum` must be declared and initialized **before** the loop, otherwise it will be initialized to its initial value at each loop, instead of retaining the sum calculated so far. Also, its scope will be limited to the loop body and not be visible in the `return` statement. Before the loop write: `int sum = 0;`.
13. You are summing up the loop variable `i` instead of the intended value at this list position. If still using this list, you would have to write `sum = sum + list[i];`, which you can simplify to `sum += list[i];`.

This is my suggestion for a `GetSum` method:

```
public int GetSum(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

Is it a bad practice to sum up the numbers like this?

You are learning C# and therefore it is a good practice to write algorithms like this one. It also works well for small ranges and is easy to understand. You could also print the intermediate results.

If, however, you need to sum up large ranges, this algorithm does not scale well, as it will spend a lot of time in the loop. In this case, better use the [formula described by @LWChris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59446173/880990). Disadvantage: it requires some math knowledge.

```
public static int GetSum(int a, int b)
{
    return (b * (b + 1) - (a - 1) * a) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea here is to break down the problem and write some code to resolve it.
In order to determine all the numbers within a range - we first must determine the range boundaries. In English we would describe it as:

Given two numbers `a` and `b` assert which the largest(upperBound) and the lowest(lowerBound).
Loop from the lowest to the largest(inclusive) and add all the values.
If `a` and `b` are equal return either.

By using my description above I would translate from English into code Eg:

*Please note I have put the equality check prior anything else. As per return early optimization, if indeed they are equal, why bother doing any other check - just return `a` or `b`.*

```
        if (a == b)
        {
            //they are the same so it doesnt matter which one we return
            return a;
        }

        if (a < b)
        {
            lowerBound = a;
            upperBound = b;
        }
        else if (a > b)
        {
            lowerBound = b;
            upperBound = a;
        }
```

Now that we know their state we can describe the code the loop as:

```
        //loop from lower to upper bound inclusive
        for (int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++)
```

*Please note the `i <= upperBound` less or equal too will enforce that the upper bound is included in the sum.*

Putting it all together we have the following:

```
    public static int GetSum(int a, int b)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int lowerBound = 0;
        int upperBound = 0;

        if (a == b)
        {
            //they are the same so it doesnt matter which one we return
            return a;
        }

        if (a < b)
        {
            lowerBound = a;
            upperBound = b;
        }
        else if (a > b)
        {
            lowerBound = b;
            upperBound = a;
        }

        //loop from lower to upper bound inclusive
        for (int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++)
        {
            result += i;
        }

        return result;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetSum(5, -7));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

In the above example the code return -13 = (-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5)

Many solutions can be adopted here in order to resolve, what I have tried to expose here is the capability to think of a design/solution before writing any actual code.

In time that will come as a second nature to any developer.

Answer (score -3):

Enumerable.range(a,b) just adds a second, entirely unessesary loop to the whole job. So you can skip that.

And acutally it seems to run *counter* to your stated goal. Stated Goal is to sume up everything between a and b. But range produces a and all numbers up to a+b+1. It does not what you expected it to do.

The real solution seems rather simple, atually:

```
public int GetSum(int a, int b)
{
    if(a == b)
       return a;

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = a; i <=b; i++){
      sum = sum + i;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

As usual, off-by-one-errors are reserved.

As for your code, you got two mistakes:

Your forloop does nothing, because you added a semicolon: `for(var i=0; i <= list.length; i++);`

Even if it did anything, the sum only exists inside the loop.

```
{
    var sum;
    sum = sum + i;
}
return sum;
```

It must be defined outside of it.

You also did not define the case if a is larger then b.

Comment: Not my dowvnote, but currently it wouldn't work. (It's not clear why you've got an optimization in there at the start, either.) More importantly, it's not clear that it would help the questioner.

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean the 1 instead of the i? Noticed and fixed that one. Also the part where I forgot the default return.

Comment: You fixed it long after asking why people were downvoting. But basically, a code-only answer isn't going to help the questioner learn what's wrong with their code, or improve. You *could* have offered advice based on their existing code, as well as offering potentially multiple solutions, each clearly-explained - but instead it's just a code dump.

Comment: @JonSkeet Because I expected people to tell me what is wrong when downvoting. Also since when is 3 mintues "long"?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Unfedined by the Question. I will not asume stuff here.

Comment: Really, because they can be negative... The answer is wrong...

Comment: @Christopher: You shouldn't expect everyone to add a comment when downvoting. Some will, some won't. If there isn't a comment, I would follow the tooltip: "This answer is not useful." And in terms of "long after" - you waited less than a minute and a half to see if there would be comments for the downvotes. I would strongly suggest that if you receive a downvote on an answer you think doesn't deserve it, you look carefully at the answer *instead* of asking for reasons.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The poster only defined what happens on equality. I can not asume expected behavior.

Comment: @Milney Overflows will break any possible infinite loop. I can only look up what exceptions/behavior Range has for that case.

Comment: The question doesn't specify that a or b should be larger than the other, so you have to solve it for both cases. You have made the assumption that b>=a, which isn't stated in the question

Comment: @ShamPooSham The OP has the **exact same asumption**. Actually he also asuemd Range does soemthing totally different from what it does too. But mistakes like those is why he asked this question.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, OP has gotten a lot of stuff wrong.

Comment: @ShamPooSham I can not understand how wanting a hint what I did wrong so I can fix it and improove is a bad attitude. Wanting to learn and improove is the best Attitude I can think off?